# Good Java Class to use for collection of mathematical Vectors

Tags: java, math, collections, vector

I'm implementing a graph (as in Vertices, Edges, not cartesian). I'm modelling the graph as a physical collection of Nodes (a class I've made).

I want to have a collection of Forces, as Vectors (in the Maths sense), to represent the forces acting upon each node, and ideally I would like to be able to perform a lookup with a Node as a key, which sounds to me like some kind of Hash Lookup Table.

What's a good collection to use, or will I have to make my own?

If anything needs clarifying, just ask.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't every `Node` simply have a field that stored a list of the `Force` s acting on it?

Comment: @biziclop That would work. I'm thinking, however, that this might be something a Node shouldn't know about, as it's only used in an external Strategy class, which is laying out the nodes in an aesthetic manner. Perhaps theoretically, a node should not have a force?

Comment: I see, fair enough then. And I suppose then that the force knowing about the node isn't an option either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your needs correctly, you basically want to do a one-to-many mapping of Node->Vector.

Provided your Node properly implements hashCode() and equals(), you could use a [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from Google Guava. This provides the `Map<Node,Collection<Vector>>` mapping automatically.

The benefit of using Multimap is that you don't need to do this:

```
Collection<Vector> vectors = nodeToVectorMapping.get(node);
if (vectors == null) {
    vectors = new HashSet<Vector>();
    nodeToVectorMapping.put(node, vectors);
}
vectors.add(vector);
```

instead, you only need to do this:

```
nodeToVectorMapping.put(node,vector);
```

The Multimap takes care of checking whether the inner Collection exists or not. If you find yourself going into a multithreaded environment, the 'do it by hand' approach would involve synchronising to ensure that two threads didn't create the Collection at the same time, and so-on. Google's Guava helps a lot with all of that, and a lot more besides.

As a big fan of Google Collections (the original home of Multimap before it was absorbed into the larger Guava project), I should also point you in the direction of [MapMaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html), which has all sorts of amazing goodness in it that you will perhaps find useful - size limitations, concurrency levels, lazy initialisation of Values based upon keys, that sort of thing. I've used these in a highly-concurrent application and they've saved my life on many an occasion! :)

Comment: @Adam I have just updated my answer - it's not Multiset, it's Multimap

Comment: Is there any reason to use Multimap over `HashMap<Node, Set<Vector>>` or `Map<Node,Collection<Vector>>`?

Comment: @Adam yes, as to why, I have added it to my answer because there's no formatting in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add the vector as a field in your Node class.

```
public class Node {
    private ForceVector force = ForceVector.getZeroForceVector();

    public ForceVector getForceVector() {
        return force;
    }
    public void addForceVector(ForceVector forceToAdd) {
        force = force.add(forceToAdd);
    }
}
```

I'm imagining ForceVector to be some (immutable) class you have written to describe a force vector.

Comment: Same comment as to biziclop, I'm not sure that's logically the best way to do it, though it might be the simplest

Answer (score 0):

If you have several forces acting on each node, you need to map a node to *a collection* of fources, for instance by using a `HashMap<Node, Set<Vector>>`. Just remember to properly implement `equals` and `hashCode` for your Nodes.

Others may suggest to you, to put the forces acting on a node, in a field in the node class. This may or may not be a good alternative. If you aim to have a graph-framework reusable in other applications, you may be better off with a separate node-to-forces-map.

Comment: This sounds like a good option, I do want that logical separation for reusability. I have multiple forces acting on one Node, yes, but I was thinking of summing them as I go. Is there benefit to storing them in a Set, less calculations perhaps?